# __memcpy_ssse3() segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

i'm working with Opencv, trying to copy some frame that captured from web camera. when copying the frame, i'm getting segmentation fault in `__memcpy_ssse3()`, line 160 or 1675.

gdb shows:

> 0  __memmove_ssse3 () at
>   ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S:1675
>
> 1  0xb75ec6d0 in cv::Mat::copyTo (this=0xbfca3450, _dst=...) at
>   /home/david/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:181
>
> 2  0xb75984f6 in cv::Mat::Mat (this=0xbfca358c, img=0xb1300c90,
>   copyData=true) at
>   /home/david/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:510

The function that calls it is `cv::MAt::Mat(IplImg *I, bool copy)`.

When I'm opening USB camera or file, everything is perfect, but when trying to read the video stream from webcam, via IP, it crashes after a minute.

I'v try to build ffmpeg and opencv without ssse3 support, and my application compiled with `-mno-seee3` flag too.

Opencv vesion is 2.4.2, but the problem exists in 2.3.1 too.
ffmpeg version is 11.1, same problem in 8.X.
gcc version is 4.6.3, Ubuntu's branch. 
The processor is Intel core2.

Any hints?

Comment: `-mno-seee3` <-- Is this a typo? Check whether you make the same typo when compiling.

Comment: Thank, it's not a typo. That's the flag that suggested by `man gcc`.

Comment: @David: that's a typo. also, the fact that it crashes on an sse is just some implementation detail, the bug is some layers above this.

Comment: Ooops, that's a typo... But in my Makefile it's ok. You probably right about that the problem is somewhere above, but i can't understand where. If it was bug in my application it probably should be caught by Opencv; but maybe not. Do you have any ideas how to try to debug it? The IplImg pointer is not NULL, but is there any way to validate the IplImg structure itself? Thanks.

Comment: sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/memcpy-ssse3.S is in glibc, has got nothing to do with opencv or ffmpeg.

Comment: try to catch the problem with `valgrind`.

Comment: Could it be down to incorrectly aligned memory? That's the most common cause for SSE related seg faults.

Comment: Hmmm. Luther, I think that it called in some place when opencv calls memcpy - in /home/david/opencv/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/core/src/copy.cpp:181 so I tried to make it use simple memcpy and not the optimized.

Comment: I can't run it with Valgrind, because it's too heavy for that, it takes forever to move there. it simply doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know if it can be unaligned memory - I'm not building any structures there, so it should be aligned by Opencv.

Comment: @comment about too heavy for Valgrind - from their site, "Valgrind is not a toy. Valgrind is first and foremost a debugging and profiling system for large, complex programs. We have had feedback from users working on projects with up to 25 million lines of code. It has been used on projects of all sizes, from single-user personal projects, to projects with hundreds of programmers."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you all, solved.
There was a mistake in locking between threads, and somehow the memory was override or freed in other thread. After fixing the lock dependencies the problem of segfault solved.

Comment: I can confirm, a similar stuation on my side. A freed memory operation, i.e a freed variable's random value was such that, caused this error.

Answer (score 10):

Segmentation faults in SSE operations are due to misaligned memory.  Try passing `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -mstackrealign` to see if that clears it up.  If it does then you need to examine your stack to find out which code is misaligning it.

Comment: Thank you Ecatmur. unfortunately it didn't work for me. I rebuilt Opencv and my program with those flags, still crashes on same thing. But I learned something, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As this question helped me to find a bug in my own code which was slightly different than just incorrect locking I was thinking to add a comment here.

Perhaps this example will be a hint and help someone trying to understand how a mutex and std::string can relate to get into a Segmentation fault.

In my code I had correct locking but a slightly different situation where destruction order and locking were playing together to create the bug

- one thread was executing the destructor of an object and got to already executing the base class destructor of that object.
  The base class offered a service to register/unregister handlers (on construction/destruction) which was protected by mutex. The execution was waiting for the mutex
- another thread that acquired the mutex tried to dispatch to a handler. This resulted in an access of a member of the derived class, a std::string, hence the segmentation fault on __memcpy_ssse3_back () as the members were already destroyed by the other thread.

The solution was to unregister the handler from the base class before proceeding with destruction.