# Compiler's alignment assumptions in std::copy

Tags: c++, stl, g++, compiler-optimization, built-in

I am dealing with a curious case where I (suddenly) started getting segmentation fault in a library code (which I wrote a while ago).

The library has a code which is responsible to copy buffers, here is the code snapshot:

```
   memory_manager_types::translation_status_t memory_manager::setMem(const uint64_t i_la, const void * const src_buff, const uint32_t i_size)
   {
        ...
        char* dst_ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pa); // pa is a 'uint64_t' which holds the destination address
        const char* src_ptr = static_cast<const char*>(src_buff);
        std::copy(src_ptr, src_ptr + i_size, dst_ptr);
```

Now when I got the segmentation fault, in the backtrace I saw that `std::copy` called to other STL methods which finally came to `__builtin_memmove` which in its turn was substituted by the compiler with `__memmove_ssse3()`.

The problem here is that the `src_buff` value in this specific case was 0xXXXXXXXXX**509** and according to what I saw in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11510444/5218277), SSSE3 instructions require some minimal alignment of the parameters. The suggestion in that answer was to try to compile the code with `-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -mstackrealign` flags which kind of resolved my problem (or maybe just masked it???).

Now if the initial assumption was correct and the problem here is the parameter's alignment, then **why** does the compiler use `__memmove_ssse3()` when the parameters sent to `std::copy` are of type `char *`for which **no alignment assumptions** can be applied?!

The original compilation was done with `g++` version 5.2.0 using the following compilation flags:

```
-m64 -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -O0 -g3
```

and after adding the additional

```
-mpreferred-stack-boundary=4 -mstackrealign
```

everything passed smoothly.

**EDIT1**

Something that I didn't mention and might be the answer to my question is that the code which uses my library is compiled with a lower version of GCC (4.2.2).

Now according to the description of the `-mstackrealign` flag:

> -mstackrealign
>
> Realign the stack at entry. On the Intel x86, the -mstackrealign option will generate an alternate prologue and epilogue that realigns the runtime stack if necessary. This supports mixing
>   legacy codes that keep a 4-byte aligned stack with modern codes that
>   keep a 16-byte stack for SSE compatibility. See also the attribute
>   force_align_arg_pointer, applicable to individual functions.

Can it be that G++ 5.2.0 assumes 16 byte stack alignment by default?

Comment: `src_buf` is also a parameter to this function (not: `src_buf`, not `*src_buf`) so the compiler might have trouble "inferring" it is 16-byte aligned. It might be `dst_buf` that is causing the trouble.

Comment: @jbapple the `dst_buf` in this case was 4k aligned, so it was OK.